# Change where Unittest projects is created

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, unit-testing, structure

Visual Studio 2013/2015 makes it possible to generate Unitettest projects and methods by right click direcly on a class method. If the project is missing, then it will be created and the problem is that this project will be created at the root of the solution, is there any way to change this so it is placed within a specific Test folder?

BestRegards

Comment: What makes you not wanting your tests in a separate project?

Comment: I know that Visual Studio wants all projects to be placed in the root of the solution in flat order but this makes it hard to find when browsing the filesystem. So I would like to have the same structure in file level as I got in the open solution. For example all unittestprojects goes in to the subfolder Unittests, all extensions goes in to the subfolder Extensions and so on.

Comment: I usualy have my solution ordered something like:
Solution
 - Stuff
 - Stuff.Tests
This way projects and test-projects are related by name. I do create a separate unit-test project for each 'production code' project though. I don't think (but do not know for sure) you can set up VS in such a way that it will do what you want. Perhaps someone else knows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way and its no point to try to defy.